# How to show Data results on click in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to show my results from a JSON file only when the search button is clicked. What is the correct way to do it?

Right now as the user types a product the results are show. I have a simple filter, that is filtering the results, but I would like to make that only appear when the button is clicked. I only want to show results when the search button is clicked.

```js
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      value: '',
      list: []
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);

    this.refresh();
  }


  handleChange(event){
    this.setState({ ...this.state, value: event.target.value })
  }
  
  refresh(){
    axios.get(`${URL}`)
      .then(resp => this.setState({...this.state, value: '', list: resp.data}));
  }

  handleSearch(product){
    this.refresh();
  }
  
   render(){
    return(
      <div className="outer-wrapper">
        <Header />
        <main>
          <Container>
            <Row>
              <Col xs={12} md={12} lg={12} className="pl-0 pr-0">
                <SearchBar 
                  handleChange={this.handleChange}
                  handleToggle={this.handleToggle}
                  handleSearch={this.handleSearch}
                  value={this.state.value}
                />
                <SearchResultBar 
                  value={this.state.value}
                />
                <Filter />
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <ProductList 
              value={this.state.value}
              list={this.state.list}
            /> 
          </Container>
        </main>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;


class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="search-input">
        <InputGroup>
          <Input placeholder='Enter Search' 
            onChange={this.props.handleChange}
            value={this.props.value}
            />
          <InputGroupAddon className='input-group-append'
            onClick={this.props.handleSearch}>
            <span className='input-group-text'>
              <i className="fa fa-search fa-lg fa-flip-horizontal"></i>
            </span>
          </InputGroupAddon>
        </InputGroup>    
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Search;


class ProductList extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    }
  }


  render(){
    let filteredSearch = this.props.list.filter(
      (product) => {
        return product.title.indexOf(this.props.value) !== -1
      }
    )
    
    return(
      <Container>
        <Row>
          {
            filteredSearch.map(item => {
              return <Product {...item} key={item._id} />
            })
          }
        </Row>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default ProductList;
```

As it stands, my list of products is being displayed in the app as soon as it loads. This seems something trivial, but I have been scratching my head in trying to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `this.refresh()` inside the constructor.  So it gets run on mount.

Just remove it from the constructor and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks man. I didn't know that the constructor worked like that. I just have to make some changes now, so I can get the correct search, but that helped.